# OSX 10.10.3 zsh: command not found: open

Tags: linux, macos, command

I can not use the open command in my mac。Who can tell me why. I wii be very grateful。

```
╭─sanyinchen@sanyinchendeMacBook-Pro  ~  
╰─$ open                                                                                                         
zsh: command not found: open
```

Comment: What's the result of `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/sanyinchen/Tools/tool/ant/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I copy the open file from other mac and copy it to the /usr/bin/

Answer (score 0):

On my mac `open` is located in:

```
$ which open
/usr/bin/open
```

You're likely missing /usr/bin from your path.

```
# To verify:
echo $PATH

# To add it (temporarily)
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

To add it permanently, add the above export line to your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: sorry,it is not work. I can't find the open file in the /usr/bin

╭─sanyinchen@sanyinchendeMacBook-Pro  /usr/bin  
╰─$ find ./ -name "open"
╭─sanyinchen@sanyinchendeMacBook-Pro  /usr/bin  
╰─$ 

It's too depressing......

Comment: Then it looks like it must have been removed somehow.
`$ ls -la /usr/bin/open
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 92912 Sep 13  2014 /usr/bin/open*`

Comment: After executing the command
```
ls: -rwxr-xr-x: No such file or directory  
ls: /usr/bin/open: No such file or directory  
ls: 1: No such file or directory  
ls: 13: No such file or directory  
ls: 2014: No such file or directory  
ls: 92912: No such file or directory  
ls: Sep: No such file or directory  
ls: root: No such file or directory  
ls: wheel: No such file or directory  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   14160  9 29  2014 /usr/bin/opendiff  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    8034  9 19  2014 /usr/bin/opensnoop  
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  922912  3 20 10:16 /usr/bin/openssl  
```